# Profit Calculation in two decimal places Javascript

Tags: javascript

In my script, I run this function to calculate profit of entries on my products table from the MySQL db. The concerning fields
are defined as decimal (10,2). It's a sales platform where I want the profit  column to be able to calculate in two decimal places when adding new products into the system. Like selling price = 50.60, original price =40.20, so the profit column should be able to give me 10.40 as the answer. Thus 50.60-40-20.

This the function i used

```
function sum() {

        var txtFirstNumberValue = document.getElementById('txt1').value;
        var txtSecondNumberValue = document.getElementById('txt2').value;
        var result = parseInt(txtFirstNumberValue) - parseInt(txtSecondNumberValue);
        if (!isNaN(result)) {
            document.getElementById('txt3').value = result;

        }
```

These are the script I used to add new product where selling price represents txt1 in the function. Whiles ,original price and profit columns represent txt2 and txt3 respectively in the function.

```
<span>Selling Price : </span>
<input type="text" id="txt1" style="width:265px; height:30px;" name="price" onkeyup="sum();" Required><br> 
<span>Original Price : </span>
<input type="text" id="txt2" style="width:265px; height:30px;" name="o_price" onkeyup="sum();" Required><br>
 <span>Profit : </span>
<input type="text" id="txt3" style="width:265px; height:30px;" name="profit" readonly><
```

My script is working correctly but thats not what I wish for. The profit column is not able to subtract decimals from another decimal value, hence,  It only show results in Integer. 
I expect If selling price = 50.60, original price =40.20, the profit column should be able to give me 10.40 as the answer. Thus 50.60-40-20.

Comment: It’s working alright. But the results doesn’t show in two decimal places. The profit is not able to subtract a decimal from another decimal value and I need help on how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you need to use `parseFloat`, not `parseInt`, to use your inputs as floating point numbers. Also you should use `toFixed(2)` on the output to ensure it is rounded to two decimal places.

```js
function sum() {

        var txtFirstNumberValue = document.getElementById('txt1').value;
        var txtSecondNumberValue = document.getElementById('txt2').value;
        var result = parseFloat(txtFirstNumberValue) - parseFloat(txtSecondNumberValue);
        if (!isNaN(result)) {
            document.getElementById('txt3').value = result.toFixed(2);

        }
        }
```

```html
<span>Selling Price : </span>
<input type="text" id="txt1" style="width:265px; height:30px;" name="price" onkeyup="sum();" Required><br> 
<span>Original Price : </span>
<input type="text" id="txt2" style="width:265px; height:30px;" name="o_price" onkeyup="sum();" Required><br>
<span>Profit : </span>
<input type="text" id="txt3" style="width:265px; height:30px;" name="profit" readonly><br>
```